# Jquery click event for the first li item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I am trying to call a function when the user clicks on the first item on an unordered list. But it does not seem to work.

This is what I did:

```
$('#listResults li').first().on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');                         
});
```

Comment: Where exactly did you put that code?

Comment: @Pointy Inside a document ready function

Comment: Need more info. There are no errors in that code.

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nts6hn27/

Comment: Well you'll need to make sure that you've really got an element with that id, and that it's a parent of your `<li>` elements. You can add a `console.log($("#listResults li").first().length)` call - it should log "1".

Comment: Dynamically created content?

Comment: @Musa Yes dynamically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dynamically created content use event delegation

```
$('#listResults').on('click', 'li:first', function() {
    alert("Wunderbar!"); 
});
```

or if the `#listResults` is creaded dynamically

```
$(document).on('click', '#listResults li:first', function() {
    alert("Wunderbar!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Is this what you want?](http://jsfiddle.net/AdGalesso/e6bj0pta/)

```
<ul id="listResults">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>

$('#listResults li:first').on('click', function() {
    alert("Wunderbar!"); 
});
```

Comment: And why would this produce a different result to the code in the question? Other than the use of a different means of selection it would select exactly the same element.

Comment: In the js no difference (":first" or ".first())". That's why I've created the small html, to see if it is the same as the user is doing